# how to switch from assembly code to c code in gdb

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I am trying to debug my c program using

```
gcc -g -lm -lpthread -std=c99 -w terminalproject.c
```

and then

```
gdb a.out
```

but when I type
`layout next`, it shows me assembly code not c code.

How to switch to C code in layout?

EDIT: I am using Red Hat Linux 6, I tried to run it in Ubuntu, It is showing C code.

p.s my code has pthreads in it.

Comment: Just a guess: there is `layout asm` and `layout src`. Do you want: `layout src` at the outset?

Comment: Tried this, it says 'No source Available'.

Comment: I've never used `layout` before. When I want to see the C source, I've always used `list`

Comment: Thanks, at least I can debug my code now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command:

```
gcc -g -lm -lpthread -std=c99 -w terminalproject.c
```

is *wrong*. Use this instead:

```
gcc -g -std=c99 -pthread terminalproject.c -lm
```

You should *never* use `-w` (suppress all warnings) flag, unless you desire painful debugging sessions.

---

> `layout src` says `No source Available`.

This likely means that you are using updated GCC, but ancient GDB. Try building recent GDB release from source -- it's usually not hard.